# Password not right but still right?

Tags: php

I'm busy with creating a login for on my website, I'm stuck with this problem:
Logging in with the right or wrong password still delivers me a succesfull login...

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM `players` 
        WHERE `username` = '" . $_POST['username'] 
        . "' AND `password` = '" . sha1($_POST['password']) 
        . "' LIMIT 1";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$get = $result->fetch_object();


if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $message = "You can't leave something blank...";
}

if (!$result) {
    $message = "Nope, not that one...";
}
```

Comment: Gah. You've got SQL injection vulnerabilities, and you should be using `password_hash`, not `sha1`, for password hashing.

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing, specially not using MD5() or SHA1(). PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: Where is this site running? `;)`

Comment: `$result` will be 'positive'/trueish when ever the query runs successfully. It _does not_ tell you if it returned any rows. Use [mysqli_result::num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) for that purpose. _AND_ switch to `password_verify()`

Comment: You should check `if (!$get)` not `if (!$result)`

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: Why are you checking for empty inputs *after* you perform the query?

Comment: @Cid It won't drop anything, since `mysqli_query()` only allows a single query. Stop propagating that myth.

Comment: @Cid - If that would have worked, it would have been a pretty mean way of making your point. Try to be a bit more constructive than destructive. It's enough to make them try a string with a single quote since that would break the query (without altering anything in their database).

Comment: That is an example to show potential vulnerabilities

Comment: @MagnusEriksson the point is not being destructive. But I could have shown harmless injections, indeed

Comment: @Cid Just post a link to the xkcd about Bobby Tables.

Comment: Yep, [this one](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: @Jeff you don't really need to count rows here, it is an unecessary step. Just do the `password_verify()`, it'll fail if the password isn't there.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: @JayBlanchard True (for a positive login test). I wanted to tell the OP what the equivalent test is he actually wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated in comments, your script is highly prone to sql injection which is extremely dangerous ESPECIALLY when handling passwords.

Please read: [Prepared statements and stored procedures](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

I will provide you working code that I use for my registrations and logins. I hope this helps you in what you are looking for. A couple things to note is that I use AJAX/JSON to pass some data back and forth between my front and back ends which I will comment my code below as to not confuse you.

```
<?php
    // starts the session
    session_start();

    // call on db connection file to execute queries below
    require 'dbconfig.php';

    // register logic
    if(isset($_POST['newusername']) && isset($_POST['newpassword'])) {
        $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username");
        $query->bindValue(':username', $_POST['newusername']);
        $query->execute();
        $check = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $query->closeCursor();
        // check if the username exists, if not then create the new user, else, send to front end and notify the user
        if($check['username'] === $_POST['newusername']) {
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($check);
        } else {
            $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (:newuser, :newpassword)");
            $query->bindValue(':newuser', $_POST['newusername']);
            $query->bindValue(':newpassword', password_hash($_POST['newpassword'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT)); // using the prepared statements to prevent injection and optimizing PASSWORD_BCRYPT for passwords
            if($query->execute()) {
                // log to my log db
                $registerLog = "New user was registered: " . $_POST['newusername'];

                $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO logs (website, entry) VALUES ('contacts', :entry)");
                $query->bindValue(':entry', $registerLog);
                $query->execute();
            }
            $query->closeCursor();
        }
    }
    // login logic
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT userid, username, password, pwreset, userlvl FROM users WHERE username = :username");
        $query->bindValue(':username', $_POST['username']);
        $query->execute();
        $auth = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $query->closeCursor();
        // check for username and verify the password
        if(count($auth > 0) && password_verify($_POST['password'], $auth['password'])) {
            // if successful, initiate $_SESSION variables
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $auth['userid'];
            $_SESSION['userlvl'] = $auth['userlvl'];
            $_SESSION['username'] = $auth['username'];

            $loginLog = "User: " . $_POST['username'] . " logged in.";

            $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO logs (website, entry) VALUES ('contacts', :entry)");
            $query->bindValue(':entry', $loginLog);
            $query->execute();
            $query->closeCursor();
            $redirect = true;
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($redirect);
            exit;
        } else {
            // if username and/or password do not match or don't exist, destroy the session.
            session_unset();
            session_destroy();
            exit;
        }
    }
?>
```

You have to unset and destroy the session if a login attempt fails or else it will just let you in every time because the script just sees that you have set the session and beyond that, it doesn't care if it really failed, it will let the user in.

I hope this provides you with an answer you need.

Comment: OP is using mysqli, not PDO.

Comment: This is ten times better, but unfortunately that's still not good enough to deploy on a production site. Writing your own authentication code is basically a no-go these days, it's too hard to get it perfect and anything less than perfect ends up creating attack vectors.

Comment: @tadman definitely agree. But on a starter level and small group use website, it can work. I am still novice myself and have MUCH to learn and am working my way to other and stronger back end languages.

Comment: "Can work" means "can be deployed" which means "can be cracked wide open at some point in the future when you're not paying attention" which means "your personal data and password hashes are now on the darknet" which is usually **really bad**. Don't go down this road in the first place. The risks are way, way too high, and pre-existing solutions are always better than hand-rolled ones.

Comment: @miken32 I understand that however I decided to post given that I FEEL PDO is a good method. Doesn't mean he has to use it.

Comment: Saying "it can work" is disagreeing because it really can't. This code, while well intentioned, is simply a ticking time bomb.

Comment: @tadman in a beginner level tho in a local environment for testing.... everyone has to start somewhere yes?

Comment: I have never actually deployed this code. This has all been learning and fun for me. That is it.

Comment: Everyone should start by **not writing their own authentication system** and instead use any of the dozens of well-documented, well-tested, community supported authentication systems. Beginners need to start out learning from good examples, not building applications from patchwork bits of Stack Overflow code. Writing something purely to learn is fine, but in that case you need to know how a real authentication system works first, and you must have a deep familiarization with [all the threats](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Cheat_Sheet_Series) you must protect against.

Comment: Not trying to harp on you in particular here, but there's a very concerning attitude in the PHP world that rolling your own *everything* is somehow a better learning experience than using a proven solution. This is not how it works. Using something like Laravel as a foundation means you get not only working, secure code, but you can dig into the Laravel source and see exactly how they do it, extend it, clone it, fork it, or do any number of things to learn and improve. This quick script doesn't teach any of that, instead it trivializes something that's actually really difficult to implement.